# More than 2 font weights per font family?

Tags: html, css, fonts

By default it is possible to implement different fonts, font weights and styles to be used later in my css styling:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "My Font Family";
  src: url("fonts/my-font-family-regular.ttf");
  font-weight: regular;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "My Font Family";
  src: url("fonts/my-font-family-bold.ttf");
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now I do want to add a `light` and a `medium` version:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "My Font Family";
  src: url("fonts/my-font-family-light.ttf");
  font-weight: 200;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "My Font Family";
  src: url("fonts/my-font-family-medium.ttf");
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

But this does not work for me. Is there a convention about the font weight values?

Comment: This should work just fine. What does your HTML and page CSS look like? (e.g. is your page CSS using font weights, rather than names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

If you want just one `font` name, you can set one font set `weight` using `class`es

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "myFont";
  src: url("fonts/my-font-family-light.ttf");
  font-weight: 200;
}

   .s1{
     font-family: myFont;
     font-weight: 200;
      }
   .s2{
     font-family: myFont;
     font-weight: 400;
      }
   .s3{
     font-family: myFont;
     font-weight: 600;
      }
```

Otherwise, assign a different name for each element

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "myLightFont";
  src: url("fonts/my-font-family-light.ttf");
  font-weight: 200;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "myMediumFont";
  src: url("fonts/my-font-family-medium.ttf");
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Check [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp) for more info

Comment: This was exactly what I tried to omit. I want to stay inside one font family and just adjust the font weights afterwards.

Comment: this is not true. If you're using @font-face declarations, changing the font weight in derivative classes will do nothing, because the single font resource file that you loaded only comes in a single weight.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There are different font-weight values and if you randomly use any value it will not reflect because they only give same result.

Like

if you give value `(100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900)`

then it will define font weight property thin to thick characters. 400 will be the same as normal and 700 will be the same as bold.

```
p.normal {
    font-weight: normal;
}

p.light {
    font-weight: lighter;
}

p.thick {
    font-weight: bold;
}

p.thicker {
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

**Reference :** [Click Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp)

Comment: Is there maybe an issue with linux operating system? I cannot see any differences between  100 and till 500 regarding this page: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_font-weight&preval=900